# Moving Certificate from Keyvault to another Keyvault in a diffrent subscription

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate

I am trying to find some way of moving my certificates from a Key Vault in one Azure Subscription to another Azure subscription. Is there anyway of doing this>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below PowerShell Script. The script first downloads the certificate from source KeyVault to some folder in you local machine. Then it imports from the local folder to Destination KeyVault.

Since you have different subscription, you can change the context between two operations.

```
    Connect-AzAccount
    
    set-azcontext "SourceSubscriptionName"
    
    $CertBase64 = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "SourceVaultName" -Name "CertName" -AsPlainText
    $CertBytes = [Convert]::FromBase64String($CertBase64)
    Set-Content -Path C:\somepath\CertName.pfx -Value $CertBytes  -Encoding Byte
    
    
    set-azcontext "DestinationSubscriptionName"
    
    $Base64String = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("C:\somepath\CertName.pfx"))
    Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "DestinationVaultName" -Name "CertName" -CertificateString $Base64String
```

Answer (score 3):

Find below an approach to move a self-signed certification created in Azure Key Vault assuming it is already created.

**--- Download PFX ---**

First, go to the Azure Portal and navigate to the **Key Vault that holds the certificate that needs to be moved**. Then, select the certificate, the desired version and click **Download in PFX/PEM format**.

[image]

**--- Import PFX ---**

Now, go to the **Key Vault in the destination subscription**, Certificates, click **+Generate/Import** and import the PFX file downloaded in the previous step.

[image]

---

If you need to automate this process, the following article provides good examples related to your question:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/kv/2016/09/26/get-started-with-azure-key-vault-certificates/

Answer (score 3):

I eventually used terraform to achieve this. I referenced the certificates from the azure keyvault secret resource and created new certificates.
the sample code here.

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.17.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

locals {
  certificates = [
    "certificate_name_1",
    "certificate_name_2",
    "certificate_name_3",
    "certificate_name_4",
    "certificate_name_5",
    "certificate_name_6"
  ]
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "old" {
  name                = "old_keyvault_name"
  resource_group_name = "old_keyvault_resource_group"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "new" {
  name                = "new_keyvault_name"
  resource_group_name = "new_keyvault_resource_group"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "secrets" {
  for_each     = toset(local.certificates)
  name         = each.value
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.old.id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "secrets" {
  for_each     = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.secrets
  name         = each.value.name
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.new.id

  certificate {
    contents = each.value.value
  }
}
```

wrote a post [here](https://blog.nebed.io/export-certificates-between-azure-keyvault-instances) as well