# Terraform Script Copy Certificate from datasource Key Vault to new Key Vault

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I am looking to copy a single certificate from Test1-KV to New-KV with teh following code, but I am receiving the following error:

azurerm_key_vault_certificate.new-cert: Creating...

Error: keyvault.BaseClient#CreateCertificate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadParameter" Message="Property policy has invalid value\r\n"

on resources.tf line 91, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "new-cert":
91: resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "new-cert" {

Code:

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "existing" {
  name                = "Test1-KV"
  resource_group_name = "Test1-RG"
  
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "new-cert" {
  name          = "new-cert"
  key_vault_id  = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "new-cert" {
  name         = "new-cert"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.new-kv.id

  certificate_policy {
    issuer_parameters {
      name = "My CA"
    }
    key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_size   = 2048
      key_type   = "RSA"
      reuse_key  = true
    }
    secret_properties {
      content_type = "application/x-pkcs12"
    }
  }
}
```

//edit part: here is my full code. to copying secrets and certificate into New-KV from Test1-KV.

```
provider "azurerm" {
    version = "~>2.14.0"
    features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name     = "${var.prefix}-RG"
  location = var.location
}

# --- Get reference to logged on Azure subscription ---
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}


resource "azurerm_key_vault" "NewKV" {
  name                        = "New-KV"
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_enabled         = true
  purge_protection_enabled    = false


  sku_name = "standard"
  

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    certificate_permissions = [
      "create",
      "delete",
      "deleteissuers",
      "get",
      "getissuers",
      "import",
      "list",
      "listissuers",
      "managecontacts",
      "manageissuers",
      "setissuers",
      "update",
    ]

    key_permissions = [
      "backup",
      "create",
      "decrypt",
      "delete",
      "encrypt",
      "get",
      "import",
      "list",
      "purge",
      "recover",
      "restore",
      "sign",
      "unwrapKey",
      "update",
      "verify",
      "wrapKey",
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "backup",
      "delete",
      "get",
      "list",
      "purge",
      "recover",
      "restore",
      "set",
    ]
 

  }
}
# -------------------- Importing Secrets from Central Key Vault to New-KV ---------------------------

# --- Defining where to import secrets ---
data "azurerm_key_vault" "existing" {
  name                = "Test1-KV"
  resource_group_name = "Test1-RG"
  
}

# --- telling what to import ---
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "Cred" {
  name         = "Cred"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id
}

# --- defining where to import ---
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "Cred" {
  name         = "Cred"
  value        = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.Cred.value
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.NewKV.id
}

# ----------------------- Importing Certificate from Central Key Vault Certificates ----------------------------------

// It stores the actual cert as a secret
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "New-Cert" {
  name         = "New-Cert"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "New-Cert" {
  name         = "New-Cert"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "New-Cert" {
  name         = "New-Cert"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.NewKV.id

  certificate {
    contents = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.New-Cert.value
  }

  certificate_policy {
    issuer_parameters {
      name = "My Company CA"
    }

    key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_size   = 2048
      key_type   = "RSA"
      reuse_key  = true
    }

    lifetime_action {
      action {
        action_type = "AutoRenew"
      }

      trigger {
        days_before_expiry = 30
      }
    }

    secret_properties {
      content_type = "application/x-pkcs12"
    }

    x509_certificate_properties {
      # Server Authentication = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
      # Client Authentication = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2
      extended_key_usage = ["1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"]

      key_usage = [
               
        "digitalSignature",
        "keyEncipherment",
      ]

      subject_alternative_names {
        dns_names = ["hello-world.io", "Hello-World"]
      }

      subject            = "CN=New-Cert"
      validity_in_months = 61
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello. What did you do to troubleshoot your issue? Did you check certificate_policy for a correct value?

Comment: yes everything is correct.

Comment: See answer to newer and very similar question "Moving Certificate from Keyvault to another Keyvault in a diffrent subscription" at https://stackoverflow.com/a/74169656/151641

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is resolved by add below code

```
data "azurerm_key_vault" "New-KV" {
  name                = "New-KV"
  resource_group_name = "New-RG"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "Test1-KV" {
  name         = "Cert"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "Cert" {
  name         = "Cert"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "Cert" {
  name         = "Cert"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.New-KV.id


 certificate {
    contents = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.Test1-KV.value
  }

certificate_policy {
    issuer_parameters {
      name = "self" (instead using original issuer use self)
    }

    key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_size   = 2048
      key_type   = "RSA"
      reuse_key  = true
    }

    secret_properties {
      content_type = "application/x-pkcs12"
    }


  }

  }
```

Comment: You can avoid hard coding the destination cert key properties by just using them from the source cert:
`key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_size   = data.azurerm_key_vault_certificate.source_cert.certificate_policy.0.key_properties.0.key_size
      key_type   = data.azurerm_key_vault_certificate.source_cert.certificate_policy.0.key_properties.0.key_type
      reuse_key  = true
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your error is specifically, but your code is not functional for what you are trying to do.  I am providing an example of the first run to create a cert, and the second run to import it into a new kv.  The trick is to source the secret generated by the cert to import it.  I validate the process worked via the thumbprints.

This is the first main.tf to generate initial kv and cert

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~>2.23.0"
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "key-vault-certificate-example"
  location = "East US"
}

output "certificate_thumbprint" {
  value = azurerm_key_vault_certificate.example.thumbprint
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                = "pearceckvcertexample"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    certificate_permissions = [
      "create",
      "delete",
      "deleteissuers",
      "get",
      "getissuers",
      "import",
      "list",
      "listissuers",
      "managecontacts",
      "manageissuers",
      "setissuers",
      "update",
    ]

    key_permissions = [
      "backup",
      "create",
      "decrypt",
      "delete",
      "encrypt",
      "get",
      "import",
      "list",
      "purge",
      "recover",
      "restore",
      "sign",
      "unwrapKey",
      "update",
      "verify",
      "wrapKey",
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "backup",
      "delete",
      "get",
      "list",
      "purge",
      "recover",
      "restore",
      "set",
    ]
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "example" {
  name         = "generated-cert"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id

  certificate_policy {
    issuer_parameters {
      name = "Self"
    }

    key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_size   = 2048
      key_type   = "RSA"
      reuse_key  = true
    }

    lifetime_action {
      action {
        action_type = "AutoRenew"
      }

      trigger {
        days_before_expiry = 30
      }
    }

    secret_properties {
      content_type = "application/x-pkcs12"
    }

    x509_certificate_properties {
      # Server Authentication = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
      # Client Authentication = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2
      extended_key_usage = ["1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"]

      key_usage = [
        "cRLSign",
        "dataEncipherment",
        "digitalSignature",
        "keyAgreement",
        "keyCertSign",
        "keyEncipherment",
      ]

      subject_alternative_names {
        dns_names = ["internal.contoso.com", "domain.hello.world"]
      }

      subject            = "CN=hello-world"
      validity_in_months = 12
    }
  }
}
```

THis is the second main.tf (different state), to generate a second kv and import the cert from the secret in the original vault.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  version = "~>2.23.0"
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                = "pearceckvcertexample"
  resource_group_name = "key-vault-certificate-example"
}

// It stores the actual cert as a secret
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example" {
  name         = "generated-cert"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "example" {
  name         = "generated-cert"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.example.id
}

output "certificate_thumbprint" {
  value = data.azurerm_key_vault_certificate.example.thumbprint
}

output "certificate_thumbprint2" {
  value = azurerm_key_vault_certificate.example.thumbprint
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "key-vault-certificate-example2"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                = "pearceckvcertexample2"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id

  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    certificate_permissions = [
      "create",
      "delete",
      "deleteissuers",
      "get",
      "getissuers",
      "import",
      "list",
      "listissuers",
      "managecontacts",
      "manageissuers",
      "setissuers",
      "update",
    ]

    key_permissions = [
      "backup",
      "create",
      "decrypt",
      "delete",
      "encrypt",
      "get",
      "import",
      "list",
      "purge",
      "recover",
      "restore",
      "sign",
      "unwrapKey",
      "update",
      "verify",
      "wrapKey",
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "backup",
      "delete",
      "get",
      "list",
      "purge",
      "recover",
      "restore",
      "set",
    ]
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "example" {
  name         = "generated-cert"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id

  certificate {
    contents = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.example.value
  }

  certificate_policy {
    issuer_parameters {
      name = "Self"
    }

    key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_size   = 2048
      key_type   = "RSA"
      reuse_key  = true
    }

    lifetime_action {
      action {
        action_type = "AutoRenew"
      }

      trigger {
        days_before_expiry = 30
      }
    }

    secret_properties {
      content_type = "application/x-pkcs12"
    }

    x509_certificate_properties {
      # Server Authentication = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
      # Client Authentication = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2
      extended_key_usage = ["1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"]

      key_usage = [
        "cRLSign",
        "dataEncipherment",
        "digitalSignature",
        "keyAgreement",
        "keyCertSign",
        "keyEncipherment",
      ]

      subject_alternative_names {
        dns_names = ["internal.contoso.com", "domain.hello.world"]
      }

      subject            = "CN=hello-world"
      validity_in_months = 12
    }
  }
}
```

Output from the run:

```
Apply complete! Resources: 3 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

certificate_thumbprint = 8ADC0C8B2255E7B19FBEFC3B348B7E075D5AB1DA
certificate_thumbprint2 = 8ADC0C8B2255E7B19FBEFC3B348B7E075D5AB1DA
```

Comment: what i am going to achieve is i have a Central Key vault with name Test1-KV there is a certificate with name new-cert i want to make a copy of that certificate into my second key vault which in new-kv. i don't want to generate a new certificate just replicate from existing to new KV.

Comment: the certificate is already in place in Test1-KV | Cetificates with name "new-cert" just wanted to make a copy of that into my "New-KV"

Comment: i have got this, this time. Error: keyvault.BaseClient#ImportCertificate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=409 Code="Conflict" Message="Certificate new-cert is currently in a deleted but recoverable state, and its name cannot be reused; in this state, the certificate can only be recovered or purged." InnerError={"code":"ObjectIsDeletedButRecoverable"}

  on resources.tf line 120, in resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "new-cert":
 120: resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "new-cert" {

Comment: my main goal is i have a resource group "Test1-RG" and in that resource group key vault instance "Test1-KV" and in "Test1-KV" i have attached a certificate which is currently is in use i want to make another copy of that certificate into "New-KV", i don't want to create a new certificate, i already have just need to make a copy of that certificate into my "New-KV" thats it.

Comment: I provided you a working example of importing a cert.  My creation script (ie the first main.tf) was for demonstration purposes.

Comment: let me give a try to the second main file and get back to you.

Comment: Error: keyvault.BaseClient#ImportCertificate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=409 Code="Conflict" Message="Certificate new-cert is currently in a deleted but recoverable state, and its name cannot be reused; in this state, the certificate can only be recovered or purged." InnerError={"code":"ObjectIsDeletedButRecoverable"}

Comment: kindly see my updated full code for you understanding.

Comment: You must have deleted the certificate of the same name on the new key vault and it has been soft deleted.  If you want to reuse the same name, you probably have to trash the key vault if you can or pick a new cert name. You might be able to recover the certificate, but I am not sure if terraform is able to update it.  It depends on how Azure API handles it.

Comment: and it is also not accepting my Certificate issuer it says **Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="BadParameter" Message="Issuer My Company CA as specified in policy was not found"**